# Динамические массивы С++. В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: c++, классы, указатели, динамические-массивы

Программа считывает из файла уже определённое количество строк и записывает информацию в класс, после чего работает с классом. Функция Memory управляет памятью. Когда мы добавляем новый объект, функция Memory должна выделять под новый добавленный объект память. Это происходит во время работы с программой, но при выполнении повторной операции по добавлению объекта программа даёт сбой. Куда копать?

Текст файла, с которым ведётся работа:

```
Скотное Тверь   6
Москва  Липецк  43
Псков   Москва  3
Ярославль   Воронеж 2
```

Код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// Объявление класса
class Routes
{
    int i = 0;
private:
    std::string StatI;
    std::string StatO;
    int tm;
public:
    Routes();
    //~Routes();
    Routes(string dep, string arr, int time);
    std::string getStatO() {return StatO;};
    std::string getStatI() {return StatI;};
    int getTm() {return tm;};
    void setStatO(std::string);
    void setStatI(std::string);
    void setTm(int time);
    int NewRouteOpt(Routes* Fill, int N, char *file);
    void Vivod(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    void Edit(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    void Write(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    int Read(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    void Sort(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file);
    int MassiveRoutes(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    int NewDefault(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file);
    void Save(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file);
    int Memory(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file);
};

// Программы, использующие класс
int Routes::NewRouteOpt(Routes* Fill, int N, char *file){
    N++;
    Memory(Fill, N, file);
    i = N - 1;
    std::string bo; // буфер отправления
    std::string bp; // буфер прибытия
    int bt; // буфер времени
    cout << "Enter Departure Station:\n>> ";
    cin >> bo;
    Fill[i].setStatO(bo);
    cout << "Enter Arrival Station:\n>> ";
    cin >> bp;
    Fill[i].setStatI(bp);
    cout << "Enter Travel Time:\n>> ";
    while (!(cin >> bt)){cout << "Invalid value!" << endl;
    cin.clear();cin.sync();}
    Fill[i].setTm(bt);
    cout << "---\nNew route:" << endl;
    cout << i << " | " << Fill[i].getStatO() << " " << Fill[i].getStatI() << " " << Fill[i].getTm() << "\n---" << endl;
    return N;}

void Routes::Vivod(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){cout.setf(ios::right);cout.width(6);
        cout << i << "|" << Fill[i].getStatO() << "\t|" << Fill[i].getStatI() << "\t|" << Fill[i].getTm() << endl;}}

void Routes::Edit(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    Routes::Vivod(Fill, N, file);
    int k;
    cout << "---\nEnter route number to edit: \n>> ";
    while (!(cin >> k) || (k>=N) || (k<0)){ cout << "Invalid value!" << endl;
    cin.clear();cin.sync();}
    std::string bo; // буфер отправления
    std::string bp; // буфер прибытия
    int bt; // буфер времени
    cout << "Enter Departure Station:\n>> ";
    cin >> bo;
    Fill[k].setStatO(bo);
    cout << "Enter Arrival Station:\n>> ";
    cin >> bp;
    Fill[k].setStatI(bp);
    cout << "Enter Travel Time:\n>> ";
    while(!(cin >> bt)){cout << "Invalid value!" << endl;
    cin.clear();cin.sync();}
    Fill[k].setTm(bt);
    cout << "---\nChanged route\n---" << endl;
    cout << k << " | "<< Fill[k].getStatO() << " " << Fill[k].getStatI() << " " << Fill[k].getTm() << endl;}

void Routes::Write(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    ofstream in(file);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        cout << i << " | " << Fill[i].getStatO() << "\t" << Fill[i].getStatI() << "\t" << Fill[i].getTm() << endl;
        if (i == N-1){
            in << Fill[i].getStatO() << "\t" << Fill[i].getStatI() << "\t" << Fill[i].getTm();}
        else{
            in << Fill[i].getStatO() << "\t" << Fill[i].getStatI() << "\t" << Fill[i].getTm() << endl;}}//delete[] Fill;
            }

int Routes::Read(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    int check = 0;
    ifstream of(file,std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    while(check == 0){
        cout << "---\nEnter name file with type:\n>> ";
        cin >> file;
        of.open(file);
        if (of){check = 1;}
        if(!of){system("cls");
            cout << "File not found!\n";
            check = 0;}}
    char *line = new char [1024];
    int col = 0, j = 0;
    while (!of.eof()){
        of >> Fill[j].StatO;
        of >> Fill[j].StatI;
        of >> Fill[j].tm;
        j++;
        of.getline(line, 1024, '\n');
        int n = strlen(line);
        if( n == 1 && n == 0){
        col--;}
        else{
        col++;}}
    delete [] line;
    of.close();
    cout << "---\nRead " << col << " rows\n---" << endl;
    return col;}

void Routes::Sort(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file){
    Routes::Vivod(Fill, N, file);
    cout << "---\nShortest route\n---" << endl;
    int mz = 1000000; // максимальное значение
        int index;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if(Fill[i].tm<=mz){
                mz=Fill[i].tm;
                index = i;}}
        cout << index << "|" << Fill[index].StatO << "\t|" << Fill[index].StatI << "\t|" << Fill[index].tm << endl;}

int Routes::MassiveRoutes(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    int pl, bf; // переменная буфера строк
    std::string bo; // буфер отправления
    std::string bp; // буфер прибытия
    int bt; // буфер времени
    cout << "How much routes you wanna add?" << endl;
    while(!(cin >> pl) || pl>=4){cout << "Invalid value!" << endl;
    cin.clear();cin.sync();}
    int i = N;
    N = N + pl;
    Memory(Fill, N, file);
    for ( int i = N-pl; i < N; i++){
        cout << "Enter Departure Station:\n>> ";
        cin >> bo;
        Fill[i].setStatO(bo);
        cout << "Enter Arrival Station:\n>> ";
        cin >> bp;
        Fill[i].setStatI(bp);
        cout << "Enter Travel Time:\n>> ";
        while(!(cin >> bt)){cout << "Invalid value!" << endl;
        cin.clear();cin.sync();}
        Fill[i].setTm(bt);
        cout << i << " | " << Fill[i].getStatO() << "\t" << Fill[i].getStatI() << "\t" << Fill[i].getTm() << endl;}
    return N;}

int Routes::NewDefault(Routes *Fill, int N, char *file){
    N++;
    Memory(Fill, N, file);
    i = N - 1;
    std::string bo; // буфер отправления
    std::string bp; // буфер прибытия
    int bt; // буфер времени
    Fill[i].StatO;
    Fill[i].StatI;
    Fill[i].tm;
    cout << "---\nNew route:" << endl;
    cout << i << " | " << Fill[i].getStatO() << " " << Fill[i].getStatI() << " " << Fill[i].getTm() << "\n---" << endl;
    return N;}

void Routes::Save(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file){
    cout << "Enter file name with type:\n>> ";
    char name[20];
    cin >> name;
    cin.clear();
    cin.sync();
    strcpy(file,name);
    Write(Fill, N, file);
    return ;}

int Routes::Memory(Routes *Fill, int N, char* file){
    int d = 0;
    d = N;
    Routes *newFill;
    newFill = new Routes[d];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        newFill[i] = Fill[i];
    }
    delete []Fill;
    Fill = newFill;
}

// конструктор по умолчанию
Routes::Routes(){
    StatO = "Dispatch";
    StatI = "Arrival";
    tm = 0;}

// возврат значений времени, станций отправления и прибытия
void Routes::setStatO(std::string ot){ // отправление
    StatO = ot;}

void Routes::setStatI(std::string pr){ // прибытие
    StatI = pr;}

void Routes::setTm(int time){ // время
    tm = time;}

// главная функция программы
int main(){
    //system("color F0");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Routes *Fill;
    Fill = new Routes[4];
    int x, tick = 0;
    char fn[20];
    cout << "---\nLaboratory work №2" << endl;
    int loc = Fill->Routes::Read(Fill, loc, fn);
    system("cls");
    Fill->Routes::Vivod(Fill, loc, fn);
    while(tick == 0){
            cout << "===\nMenu\n===\n1. Create new route (default)\n2. Create new route (with parameters)\n3. Create new routes\n4. Edit and view routes\n5. View shortest route\n6. Exit" << endl;
            cout << "---\n>> ";
            cin >> x;
            cin.clear();cin.sync();
    switch(x){
    case 1: // создание объекта с помощью конструктора по умолчанию
        system("cls");
        loc = Fill->Routes::NewDefault(Fill, loc, fn);
        Fill->Routes::Vivod(Fill, loc, fn);
        break;
    case 2: // создание объекта с помощью конструктора с параметрами
        system("cls");
        loc = Fill->Routes::NewRouteOpt(Fill, loc, fn);
        Fill->Routes::Vivod(Fill, loc, fn);
        break;
    case 3: // создание объекта
        system("cls");
        loc = Fill->Routes::MassiveRoutes(Fill, loc, fn);
        system("cls");
        Fill->Routes::Vivod(Fill, loc, fn);
        break;
    case 4: // редактирование и просмотр свойств
        system("cls");
        Fill->Routes::Vivod(Fill, loc, fn);
        do{
        cout << "---\n1.Edit\n2.Write to file\n3.Write to new file\n4.Exiting the subprogram\n---" << endl;
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> x;cin.clear();cin.sync();
        if (x==1){
                system("cls");
                Fill->Routes::Edit(Fill, loc, fn);}
        else if (x==2){
                system("cls");
                Fill->Routes::Write(Fill, loc, fn);}
        else if (x==3){
                system("cls");
                Fill->Routes::Save(Fill, loc, fn);}
        else if (x==4){
                system("cls");
                break;}
        else {system("cls"); cout << "---\nInvalid input!\n---" << endl;}}
        while (true);
        system("cls");
        break;
    case 5: // сортировка
        system("cls");
        Fill->Routes::Sort(Fill, loc, fn);
        break;
    case 6: // выход из программы
        system("cls");
        Fill->Routes::Write(Fill, loc, fn);
        return 0;
    default:
            system("cls");
            cout << "---\nError!\n---" << endl;
            break;}}}'
```

Comment: В `main()` очень странно выглядит строка `int loc = Fill->Routes::Read(Fill, loc, fn);` - используете в параметре функции еще не инициализированную переменную `loc`. Не уверен, что проблема только в этом.

Comment: Проблема, разумеется, в том, что указатель передается в функцию `Memory` по значению. Новое его значение из функции наружу не возвращается. Это вдоль и поперек изъезженная ошибка новичка, которая тут встречалась уже миллион раз. Писать все заново лень, а дубликаты найти не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так надо

```
void Init(int*& p, int i)
{
    p = new int(i);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int* p = nullptr;
    Init(p, 1000);

    return 0;
}
```